# Laravel: Parsing XML with SimpleXML namespace issue

Tags: php, xml, laravel, simplexml

**UPDATE**

I added some logging and my first log, the response, is returning the XML.  But after I put the response in `simplexml_load_string` and then log that variable, it is empty in my log.

```
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', $url);
    log_info($res->getBody()-getContents());

    $orders = simplexml_load_string($res->getBody()->getContents());
    log_info($orders);
```

### -------

### ------

**Original Question**

I am trying to parse the XML at the below here using SimpleXML.  In my code, I have:

```
    $orders = simplexml_load_string($res->getBody()->getContents());
    $orders->getNamespaces(true);

    foreach ($orders->TrackInfo as $order) {
        // logic
    }
```

This *was* working for me for the last few days but now I am getting the following error `Error: Call to a member function getNamespaces() on boolean`.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

---

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TrackResponse>
   <TrackInfo ID="9405509205328001086959">
      <Error>
         <Number>-2147219283</Number>
         <Description>A status update is not yet available on your Priority Mail&lt;SUP&gt;&amp;reg;&lt;/SUP&gt; package. It will be available when the shipper provides an update or the package is delivered to USPS. Check back soon. Sign up for Informed Delivery&lt;SUP&gt;&amp;reg;&lt;/SUP&gt; to receive notifications for packages addressed to you.</Description>
         <HelpFile />
         <HelpContext />
      </Error>
   </TrackInfo>
</TrackResponse>
```

Comment: `simplexml_load_string()` can return false when it fails to load the XML, although the XML you show seems valid.  You will need to check what `$res->getBody()->getContents()` is giving when it fails.

Comment: @NigelRen yep, I checked the XML by logging it.  I did `log_info($orders)` right after I set `$orders = simplexml_load_string($res->getBody()->getContents());`  It's logging the exact XML that I pasted.  That is what has me stumped.

Comment: making an EDIT now

Comment: The return value of `simplexml_load_string()` is a `SimpleXMLElement` and it cannot be treated as a string. Use `$orders->asXML()` instead.

Comment: As an aside: `$orders->getNamespaces(true);` on its own doesn't do anything. It's a function for getting information out of the object, but you're not doing anything with the information.